# Removing an overlay using green screen footage?

Tags: after-effects

Ive got the composition, available publically:

And a green screen of the overlay used given from the Sea of Thieves 'Creator Crew' program.

[image: green screen overlay]

How can I use this to remove the overlay from the fireplace, and fill in from other frames something passable.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Chroma Keying".

It works by sampling a color (in either 2D or 3D space, but you don't have to worry about that) and it, simply put, exchanges that color with the alpha channel - thus making the hue transparent. If you're working with Streamlabs OBS, regular OBS, After Effects or something similar, Chroma Keying is built into these programs. For a good result and knowledge about screen mattes, despill and other things to keep in mind while keying, check out the tutorials by andrew kramer.

Comment: I wanted to do the exact inverse of Chroma Keying. Remove footage that has been chroma-keyed, and fill it with anything, previous frame content, content aware fill, solid color.

I have the original overlay with green, and the final product.

Comment: Oh I see. In this case, you can duplicate the footage so you have two instances of it. One layer, you'll want to key, then in track mattes, you can set the un-keyed layer to "inverse alpha mask" from your keyed layer. This will effectively copy the inverse alpha channel from your keyed layer onto the unkeyed layer. Now, you can move anything below the "hole" you just created - content aware fill, solid color, etc.